# Modify CSS of element with no class or id by element parent's selector

Tags: css

```
<span class="avia-menu-text"><img src="data:image/png;base64,etc..." title="ESP (es_ES)" alt="ESP"></span>
```

I have a base64 image in a Wordpress theme (a language flag) that is rectangular and I want to make it circular. I can't locate the origin of the base64 image so I can't modify the data. The parent  has a class name, but the image does not.

In CSS I have tried

> img<.avia-menu-text{ border-radius:100% }

Any suggestions - ideally using only CSS and definitely without JQuery?

Comment: Is it working when you add that style inline ?

<img style="border-radius:100%" src="data:image/png;base64,etc..." title="ESP (es_ES)" alt="ESP">

Comment: @BoltClock the question is wrong, it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inverse your selector.

try

```
.avia-menu-text img{
border-radius:50px;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, that worked well. I'll accept when it lets me

Comment: @grateful You're welcome